# lookahead greediness not working

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

i just learned lookahead in regular expression, but there is one detail that is bugging me:

```
% set test abcdehehfkdehemno

% regexp {([^ ])*.} $test match

1

% set match

abcdehehfkdehemno

% regexp {((?=dehe).)*.} $test match

1

% set match

a
```

why the `([^ ])*` is greedy and the `((?=dehe).)*` is not, i expect the lookahead version return m instead a ?

Comment: Are you just asking for the regex explanation? Is it Tcl? What is your real problem? What pattern do you need to match, or what results do you expect per a given input string?

Comment: Both regexes apply greediness. In the second, however, assertion doesn't pass.

Comment: These patterns can be tested at http://regex101.com. The first one just matches 0+ chars other than space and any single char after (thus matching the whole string). The second one requires a substring starting with `dehe`, but as there is no `dehe` at the beginning, and the subpattern can match an empty string, the next `.` in the pattern matches the first `a`.

Comment: why it has to be at the beginning of the string ? there are two `dehe` and i am expecting the look ahead to be greedy and match the second `dehe`.

Comment: @revo but which assertion ?